# How to obtain Access controls or permissions for the user?, If the user is authenticated in the third party services

Tags: aem, acl, saml, saml-2.0

If Users are not available in AEM instance and authenticated in third party services via SAML, How to obtain Access controls or permissions for the user? Will AEM allows to set or apply permissions on the users who are not available in AEM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [SAML Integration Documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/saml-demo.html)

> **Limitations**
>   User Must Exist in AEM Users logging in via the
>   handler must exist, or if missing must be created in, AEM (“Autocreate
>   CRX Users” must be checked). This is because the Sling authentication
>   framework, which the  SamlAuthenticationHandler is a part of, extracts
>   user credentials from the SAMLResponse and logs into the JCR
>   repository using those credentials.

Also refer this [link on Adobe AEM forum](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__w2ui-please_validatethe.html)